# Return variant from a lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, variant

I have this simple lambda:

```
    std::variant<int, char> myLambda = []() { // no suitable user-defined conversion from "type" to "std::variant<int, char>" exists
        std::variant<int, char> res;

        if (true)
        {
            res = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            res = 'c'; 
        }

        return res;
    };
```

But it doesn't compile, producing error `no suitable user-defined conversion from "type" to "std::variant<int, char>" exists`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to call the lambda change the last `};` to `}();`  Typo?

Comment: @RichardCritten No, I just want to initialize lambda, not to call it.

Comment: @RichardCritten However, you made me understand my mistake, thanks!

Comment: A problem with 2 solutions .... I suggested the wrong one.  Glad the answers below helped you.

Comment: Hopefully a lesson in explaining what you want to do!

Comment: Possibly: `auto myLambda = [&]() -> std::variant<int, char> { if (cond) { return 1; } else { return 'c'; }}};`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks! didn't know this way to define return type. Much cleaner!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lambda expression type is wrong. You're trying to bind to `std::variant<int, char>`. Lambda expressions type name is impl-defined. Use `auto`:

```
auto processProjectFile = []() {
    std::variant<int, char> res;
    if (true) {
        res = 1;
    } else {
        res = 'c'; 
    }
    return res;
};
```

Optionally, you can cast the lambda type to `std::function` replacing `auto` by `std::function<std::variant<int, char>(void)>`.

But if you intend to call the lambda, just replace `};` at the end by `}();`.

Comment: Yep, this is what I've missed. Thanks. Stupid error I have had. BTW the `std::function` part is handy! Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `ClosureType`. The name of a type of a lambda is impl-defined

Answer (score 7):

Either you mean

```
std::variant<int, char> v = []() {
    std::variant<int, char> res;

    if (true)
    {
        res = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        res = 'c'; 
    }

    return res;
}();
^^^
```

Or you mean

```
auto myLambda = []() {
    std::variant<int, char> res;

    if (true)
    {
        res = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        res = 'c'; 
    }

    return res;
};
```

Lambda expressions have unique types.